# MeshGrid for Triangle Elements

Tags: matlab, element, contourf

I want to build a `contourf` plot of a certain aspect in my Plate. The plate is divided in triangle elements, which I have the coordinates (x,y) of each knot of the triangle.

So, How can I make a `meshgrid` for my knots so I can make my `contourf` plot?? I have the coordinates of everything and have the value of my function `Z` in each knot. (I'm a beginner in Matlab, sorry for this "basic" question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is just to visualise the triangles then there is another way that's probably simpler and more robust (see the end of this post).

If you definitely need to generate contours then you will need to interpolate your triangular mesh over a grid. You can use the `scatteredInterpolant` class for this (documentation [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant-class.html?searchHighlight=scatteredinterpolant)). It takes the X and Y arguments or your triangular vertices (knots), as well as the Z values for each one and creates a 'function' that you can use to evaluate other points. Then you create a grid, interpolate your triangular mesh over the grid and you can use the results for the countour plot.

The inputs to the scatteredInterpolant`have to be linear column vectors, so you will probably need to reshape them using the`(:)`notation.

So let's assume you have triangular data like this

```
X = [1 4; 8 9];
Y = [2 3; 4 5];
Z = [0.3 42; 16 8];
```

you would work out the upper and lower limits of your range first

```
xlimits = minmax(X(:));
ylimits = minmax(Y(:));
```

where the (:) notation serves to line up all the elements of X in a single column.

Then you can create a `meshgrid` that spans that range. You need to decide how fine that grid should be.

```
spacing = 1;
xqlinear = xlimits(1):spacing:xlimits(2);
yqlinear = ylimits(1):spacing:ylimits(2);
```

where linspace makes a vector of values starting at the first one (`xlimits(1)`) and ending at the third one (`xlimits(2)`) and separated by `spacing`. Experiment with this and look at the results, you'll see how it works.

These two vectors specify the grid positions in each dimension. To make an actual `meshgrid`-style grid you then call `meshgrid` on them

```
[XQ, YQ] = meshgrid(xqlinear, yqlinear);
```

this will produce two matrices of points. `XQ` holds the x-coordinates of every points in the grid, arranged in the same grid. `YQ` holds the y-coordinates. The two need to go together. Again experiment with this and look at the results, you'll see how it works.

Then you can put them all together into the interpolation:

```
F = scatteredInterpolant(X(:), Y(:), Z(:));
ZQ = F(XQ, YQ);
```

to get the interpolated values `ZQ` at each of your grid points. You can then send those data to `contourf`

```
contourf(XQ, YQ, ZQ);
```

If the contour is too blocky you will probably need to make the `spacing` value smaller, which will create more points in your interpolant. If you have lots of data this might cause memory issues, so be aware of that.

If your goal is just to view the triangular mesh then you might find [`trimesh`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trimesh.html) does what you want or, depending on how your data is already represented, `scatter`. These will both produce 3D plots with wireframes or point clouds though so if you need contours the interpolation is the way to go.